# digital input pins on arduino nano with standard firmata and pyfirmata are always 'None'

Tags: arduino-nano, pins, firmata

[image]

I have connected pin D2 on my arduino nano to high, and tried it out with an arduino c program and it works.  However, when I load standard firmata onto the the controller from the arduino IDE and try the following python program:

```
import pyfirmata

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyUSB0')

for x in range(2,14):
    print("%s %s" % (x, board.get_pin("d:%s:i" % x).read()))
```

I get this:

```
$ venv/bin/python test.py 
2 None
3 None
4 None
5 None
6 None
7 None
8 None
9 None
10 None
11 None
12 None
13 None
```

I can write digital pins with fermata and pyfirmata, but I can't *read*.

I have also tried this:

```
import pyfirmata

board.digital[2].mode = pyfirmata.INPUT
board.digital[3].mode = pyfirmata.INPUT

for x in range(2,14):
    print("%s %s" % (x, board.digital[x].read()))
```

and other combinations, and always get None

(disconnecting the wire in the picture doesn't change anything either)

---

I have also just repeated the experiment with an arduino uno and get the same result

---

so I guess my questions are:

- Can anybody spot anything obvious that I am doing wrong?
- Can anybody confirm that pyfirmata input ever works?
- What did you do that I am not doing?

Comment: what should the resistor do?

Comment: Unless I have done something totally wrong, it is a pull down resistor in case I want to disconnect the yellow wire to see a low signal on `D2`.  It was necessary when I tested the set-up with arduino-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"None" indicates that there is no data to be found by read() because the incoming serial stream has never been serviced.  Launch an Iterator to start a new Python thread that services the serial port in the background.

```
it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
it.start()
```